# Roundoff Error by a machine number

Tags: numerical-methods

What is the roundoff error when we represent $2^{-1} + 2^{-25}$ by a machine number? (Note: this refers to *absolute* error, not *relative*)

Please, help

Comment: $0$, when we're using IEEE754 `double`s. What do you know about the representation of "machine numbers"?

Comment: it has the form of $sign$ $exponent$ $mantissa$ ? Like $0$ $00000000$ $00000000000000000000000$ for 0 in decimal ?
Could you explain your answer?

Comment: How many bits for exponent and mantissa? How are the bits to be interpreted? (Yes, I'm pretty sure it's the IEEE754 format, but do you know what that means?)

Comment: sign - 1 bit, mantissa- 23, exponent - 8?

Comment: There are 24 bits for the mantissa. The leading one is implied so this number can just fit without loss of precision.

Comment: Yes, but how are the bits to be interpreted, what does the bit pattern `0x30400000`, with sign bit $0$ exponent bits $0110000$ and mantissa bits $10000000000000000000000$ _mean_?

Comment: @WarrenHill No, this number needs $25$ bits of precision, so it gets rounded to $\frac12$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Single precision IEE754 number.

You have a sign bit: 0 is positive, 1 is negative

8 bits for the exponent with a -127 offset (range -127 to +128)

A 24 bit mantissa.  The top bit is always assumed to be 1 so only 23 bits are stored.

For your example you need 25 bits of mantissa so $2^{-25}$ is too small to fit and the closest you can get is $2^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}$

The absolute error is therefore $2^{-25}$.

Note.  With double precision numbers the absolute error would be zero.